# Fix this issue by adding the following to I:\StratejiSoft\android\app\build.gradle:

Tags: flutter

```
One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version.
Fix this issue by adding the following to I:\StratejiSoft\android\app\build.gradle:
android {
  compileSdkVersion 33
  ...
}


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
   > One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:

     Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.5.1' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 32 or higher.
     Compilation target for module ':app' is 'android-31'

     Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 32 or higher.
     Compilation target for module ':app' is 'android-31'

     Dependency 'androidx.webkit:webkit:1.5.0' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 32 or higher.
     Compilation target for module ':app' is 'android-31'

     Dependency 'androidx.emoji2:emoji2-views-helper:1.2.0' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 32 or higher.
     Compilation target for module ':app' is 'android-31'

     Dependency 'androidx.emoji2:emoji2:1.2.0' requires 'compileSdkVersion' to be set to 32 or higher.
     Compilation target for module ':app' is 'android-31'

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Friends, I haven't tried every code, I always see different errors. and yes, I have always changed the version series, again the same error did not exist 2 days ago

Comment: I am Using Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set both `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 33 in your build.gradle(app) file.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33 // <-- This
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        targetSdkVersion 33 // <-- and this too
        // ...
    }
}
```